# CartThrob Checkout randomly not saving data

Tags: cartthrob, checkout, saving

EE 2.9.0
CartThrob Pro 2.6

I have a site where orders are placed and the customer chooses the pickup date from a radio selection. The pickup dates are created in the menu channel and then fed into the checkout.

On Checkout - second page the relevant code is:

```
        {exp:channel:entries channel="menus" url_title="{segment_3}"}

        {exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form id="delivery-form" name="delivery-form" class="form-horizontal parsley" return="checkout/cart" required="custom_data[order_pickup_delivery]"}

        <h2>Choose your method of Pickup/Delivery</h2>
        <p id="note">If you have a special request regarding delivery time or date, you enter it on the next screen.</p>

        {menu_pickup_delivery}
            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="custom_data[order_pickup_delivery]" value="{menu_pickup_delivery:option}" {if menu_pickup_delivery:default}checked="checked"{/if}> {menu_pickup_delivery:option}</label>
        {/menu_pickup_delivery}

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Continue" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" formnovalidate>

        {/exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

The issue is that CartThrob is randomly not saving this data even though there is a default radio button. When I look in the CP edit page for the orders channel I can see random entries with no data saved for the delivery date.

However on testing in Chrome, FF, and IE I was unable to replicate data not saving when I did not change the radio selection or when I did change it.

Any thoughts on what could be happening here?